# Create a FormGroup Object via My Form inputs

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-code

I have created a Form called `compaign`! My purpse is to register Form's inputs data within a FormGroup Object and send it to my backend ! The first thing I have done it ; is that I created a `FormGroup` model i used the class   `CompaignForms`  , then i had to instanciate this `class` using a local variable called `compaignexample` ; After that i have created the main `FormGroup`  object called `compaignform` and i had to initialize it with `compaignexample` attributes using `get` method ! But the problem is in my template becauz i 
 worked with `formControl` and `ngModel` at the beginning  ! So i was urged to delete the directive`[(ngModel)]` and i kept only`formControlName`! However , the console displays that i have to make a parent component ( `[formGroup]` ) ! I tried it in vain !! Please how can i fix that problem ! 
I mentionned my stackblitz demo and it doesnt contain the whole project !! there is a path problem there ! but the only problem which figure out currently is the one above !!

[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wevxte?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcompaignexample.model.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this code `#compaignForm="ngForm"` from your form tag and add this `[formGroup]="compaignexample"` to your form tag.

`<form [formGroup]="compaignexample" (ngSubmit)="saveCompaign()"></form>`

`ngForm` is used when creating Template-driven forms.